# How to insert data in mysql table randomly

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a script that get data from other website and insert or add it in mysql table. When I use to get data from website, It runs correctly but when I insert it in mysql I cannot do that thing. it shows me error, i.e.

```
 Error: INSERT INTO body (title) VALUES (Offworld Trading Company Free Download)
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Trading Company Free Download)' at line 2Error: INSERT INTO body (body) VALUES (

Here is my code see what am I doing wrong.

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$xml = simplexml_load_file("sitemap.xml");
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "kuta";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
foreach ($xml->url as $s) {
    $s = $s->loc;
    $html = file_get_html($s);
    $element = $html->find('div[class=post-content clear-block]');
    // Find all links 
    $vez = $html->find('div[class=post-date]');
    $p = '|<a [^>]*href="http://<Some Url>[^"]*"[^>]*>.*</a>|iU';
    $h = $html->find('h1[class=title]');
    if (empty($vez)) {
        foreach ($h as $ha) {

            $q = strip_tags($ha->plaintext);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO body (title) VALUES ($q)";
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
        }
        foreach ($element as $a) {
            if ($a === end($element)) {
                $m = preg_replace($p, '', $a);
            }
            $m = strip_tags($m, '<p><a><img><br /><br><div>');
            $sql = "INSERT INTO body (body) VALUES ($m)";
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
        }
    }
}
$conn->close();
```

I have created table named body, all the things are going well, When I insert data like

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (title, body)
VALUES ('Aditya', 'pandey')";
```

Show me where am I wrong and correct me. Your answer are highly appreciable, Please help me.

Comment: Can you show us the code around this variable?

Comment: first time when I use $sql variable

Comment: missing semicolon `$q=strip_tags($ha->plaintext)`

Comment: Did you till get the issue?

Comment: Yes sir. I cannot install data in my mysql table

Comment: Please see the new error

Comment: I think you should add single quotes for string fields like this: `"INSERT INTO body (title) VALUES ('$q')"` around `$q` and `$m` also.

Comment: @lolka_bolka: You're right, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you inserting values into string fields, the right MySql syntax is to wrap them around with a quote `'`

For example:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO body (body) VALUES ('$m')";
```

Do it also for `$q` and all the strings. I suggest you to escape them with `mysqli_real_escape_string` function to avoid sql injection and syntax errors.

Comment: I insert data like title in nth id than body in (n+1)th id. I want to do this in same id.

Comment: if you want to do this, first learn how do you need to insert data correctly to a table. And I really have no idea what is your title means... Your whole post is about your syntax error, so, first fix theme, and please ask the question in another question with the related code pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Try these codes;

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO body (`title`) VALUES ('$q')";
```

and,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO body (`body`) VALUES ('$m')";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I insert data like title in nth id than body in (n+1)th id. I want to do this in same id